# How to plot titles of items on arules plot?

Tags: r, list, plot, associations, arules

I have a list retail.hi of transactions that contains ids of items and I also have an info-df with ids and titles.

I'd like to see titles on the plot instead of ids.
How can I do this?

The problem is that there are some ids that don't exist in my info-df, and for them i'd like to plot id instead of title.

I do plot like this:

```
plot(retail.hi, method = "graph", control = list(type = "items"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the item labels in the labels column in

```
 itemInfo(retail.hi)
```

You probably need to match on your ids and then do this:

```
 iteminfo(retail.hi)$labels <- your_new_labels
```